# How do I turn off the annoying clicking sound when browsing web pages in Internet Explorer?

Tags: internet-explorer

When I browse web pages in Internet Explorer, especially AJAX heavy sites, IE constantly clicks at me. How do I stop the madness?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you don't want to hack the registry:

Go to **Control Panel > "Sounds and Audio Devices"**.

Select the **"Sounds" tab**.

Scroll down to the **"Windows Explorer"** section:

Set the following sounds to (None):

- **"Complete Navigation"**
- **"Start Navigation"**

Comment: Is this action equivalent to other answers posted, including the accepted answer?  If so, kudos (+1) to you for a solution that is usable "for the rest of us."  (Can you imagine trying to explain how to use the Registry Editor to an average, non-technical user?)

Answer (score 10):

You need to disable the "Start Navigation" sound that is part of the Explorer shell. Disabling this sound will disable it for both Internet Explorer AND the Windows Shell.

You can do this via a simple registry key change as well. Create a file called **Disable Start Navigation Sound.reg** and place the following contents:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\AppEvents\Schemes\Apps\Explorer\Navigating\.Current]
@=""
```

Comment: This is usually the first thing I do on any new Windows installation. Likewise turning off key clicks on iPhones...

Comment: +1 for that. People on trains who leave the key clicks switched on for their phones drive me mental!

Answer (score 1):

This disables windows navigation sounds, I think it might work for IE also:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\AppEvents\Schemes\Apps\Explorer\Navigating\.default]
@=" "
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\AppEvents\Schemes\Apps\Explorer\Navigating\.current]
@=" "
```

Answer (score 0):

XP:

Go to 'Control Panel'
Double-click on the 'Sounds and Audio Devices' control panel
Click the Sounds tab.
Scroll down in the 'Program events' list until you find the 'Windows' section, then highlight 'Default Beep.'
Change the 'Sounds' drop down menu at the bottom of the dialog to '(None).'
Press the OK button when done.